# Enable Spring JWT Authentication and OAuth2 Authentication on Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I’m developing a spring boot application where users can register into the system by providing the necessary information. The platform should provide users to authenticate with their registered user credentials or social media login credentials (google/Facebook).

For simple user authentication, I want to create a simple post request to the server with the user name and password and after validating, the server returns a token. I do not want to use the spring security form login here.

But for social media logic, I believe I have to go with oAuth.

I’m new to spring Boot and spring security. Do I need to integrate both JWT authentication and OAuth authentication for this scenario? A suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you. describe about user management (user registration, login, logout) are standard features of OAuth2 / OpenID **authorization-servers**. You should pick one "from the shelf" either on premise (like Keycloak) or in the cloud (like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, and many others). Many solutions include "social" identities federation.

REST APIs are **resource-servers**. See [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for security configuration and tests with mocked identities.

UIs are **clients**. You should use an OAuth2 client lib to handle OAuth2 flows. Find one for your framework Spring has one if your UI is generated on server with Thymeleaf or alike, but there are libs for Angular, React and other frameworks running in browsers.

Spring OAuth2 client libs can also be used in BFF (backend for front-end) scenario when browser client **is not OAuth2** (it is secured with session, not access-token) and talks to an app on the server which is the OAuth2 client (`spring-cloud-gateway` is a sample but you could also write your own app with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`). This app translates the request with session into into one with access-token before forwarding it to resource-server. The aim is to hide tokens from Javascript in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This finds really helpful. What if I want to implement my own authentication and authorization server (Instead of using 3rd party provider) apart from social media sign-in? In that case, how can I handle the scenario? Let me clear this up more

1. My own authentication and authorization server  (No 3rd party provider)
2. Social media sign in

How this is possible with a single spring Boot application?

Comment: You use a framework like Spring authorization-server project and re-invent the wheels (social login, roles management screens, connection to LDAP, multi-factor authentication, etc.). This will be much more work than you can imagine (and incredibly much more than configuring a Keycloak instance)